# Formal language encoding WS2S and closed under complementation.

Tags: logic, model-theory, automata

It is known that the relations encoded in WS1S are also represented by the words accepted by certain finite automata and thus can be represented as regular languages.

A similar connection holds between WS2S, tree automata and context-free languages (see the work of Doner "Tree acceptors...").

However, context-free languages are not closed under complementation.

Is there a formal language that "represents" the relations of WS2S and yet it is closed under union, intersection and complementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look into regular languages of trees https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_automaton. The basic idea is that just as you can index a position within a word by a natural number, you can index a position within a rooted binary tree with ordered children (child nodes are always left-children or right-children) by a first-order element of WS2S. Here the two successor operations operate on the nodes of trees and are left-child and right-child. So a first-order element of WS2S describes the path to navigate to a node from the root node.

So the thing that corresponds to a word in the WS2S case is a rooted binary tree with ordered children whose nodes are labeled with characters from some finite alphabet. Given such a tree, we get an element of WS2S for each character that's just "the set of positions in the tree where this character occurs".

A regular tree expression (I'm looking at Downey and Fellows' "Parameterized Complexity" Definition 6.39, but you can also find this in Gecseg and Steinby's "Tree Automata" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.06233) definition 2.5.1) is constructed recursively:

Starting from:

- the empty set ($\emptyset$)
- for each character $a \in \Sigma$, the language which is just a one-node tree with that node labeled $a$ (denoted $a$)

Freely apply the following operations: $L, W$ regular tree languages, $a$ a character in $\Sigma$:

- $L \cdot_a W$: for each labeled tree $T$ in $W$, replace all leaves with the label $a$ by (potentially different) labeled trees in $L$.
- $L^{*a} = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} \underbrace{L \cdot_a \cdots \cdot_a L}_{n}$
- $L \odot_a W$: for each labeled tree $T_1 \in L, T_2 \in W$, construct a tree with root labeled by $a$ and children $T_1$ and $T_2$.
- $L + W$: union

Comment: My understanding is that these are also not closed for complementation

Comment: Maybe S2S would work better for this but i dont know its formal language counterpart

Comment: The regular tree languages are closed under complementation: this is easy to see when you look at deterministic bottom up tree automata, since you just complement the accept states.

Comment: Is there a standard way of representing a regular tree language? For regular languages I know regular expressions, for regular tree languages I'm guessing I need to use a "regular tree grammar"?

Comment: I've added the definition of regular tree expression to my answer, but there are also regular tree grammars similar to regular grammars